# Pagination for the LazyColumnFor

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-lazyfor

Jetpack compose released with alpha version and I want to implement paging for the `LazyColumnFor` compose function. But I can't understand how we can do this because I can't find something to determine scroll position or something similar. Do we have this opportunity right now or this mechanism will be add in the future?

Comment: `LazyColumnForIndexed()` might help. See [this Medium post](https://medium.com/@DamianPetla/list-pagination-with-jetpack-compose-6c25da053858).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is, as of the initial alpha release, not currently a way to detect scroll position.  It will be added later, though, with an API something like:

```kotlin
Column {
    val state = rememberLazyListState()
    Text("First item: ${state.firstVisibleItemIndex}")
    LazyColumnFor(
        (0..100).toList(),
        Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        state = state
    ) {
        Text("$it", style = currentTextStyle().copy(fontSize = 40.sp))
    }
}
```

This will (once that is merged) display the first visible scroll position in the list.